# Silverlight 5 (RC) PivotViewer control

Tags: pivotviewer

I can't seem to find System.Windows.Controls.Pivot.dll anywhere in the sdk folders. Does anyone know the whereabouts of this file? I'm trying to reference it so that I can add it Visual Studio Toolbox for use in my silverlight 5 (RC) test project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the files should be in Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v5.0\Libraries\Client.. be sure to have the latest RC installed as the first beta didn't include the pivotviewer.